# SQL - column value depending on if another column value appears in a third column

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a table where column three value will depends on if the value of column 1 is present in any row of column 2.

Here's what the table I want to create should look like:

```
doc_name    doc_used    tool
---------------------------------
MEA123     MEA123       tool1      
MEA123     Null         tool1
MEA555     Null         Null
MEA554     Null         Null
MEA123     Null         tool1
```

But I only manage to get it working for the first line :

```
doc_name    doc_used    tool
---------------------------------
MEA123     MEA123       tool1      
MEA123     Null         Null
MEA555     Null         Null
MEA555     Null         Null
MEA123     Null         Null
```

Here's the codes I tried:

```
CREATE TABLE `/mydataset` AS (
SELECT 
doc_name,
doc_used,
(CASE 
   WHEN doc_name  in  (doc_used) then 'tool1'
END) as tool

FROM  `/test_dct_tool`)
```

The list of possible doc_used is unknown so I would like to check if value of column doc_name exists in the whole list of values of col doc_used. I've tried to use "exists" and "in (select doc_used from )" but couldn't get anywhere either.

Comment: Your code is saying to put tool1 in tool if doc_used is within doc_name. Which is why you're getting that result. As in column 1 is only present in column 2 for the first row.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your sample CREATE TABLE is invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT doc_name, doc_used,
       (CASE WHEN doc_name IN (SELECT t2.doc_used FROM `/test_dct_tool`) 
             THEN 'tool1'
        END) as tool
FROM `/test_dct_tool` t;
```

Answer (score 0):

below query will   return all the value of your table where others 2 column contain values of column 1

```
   select * from table1 where doc_name in (
    select doc_used as col from table1
     union
    select  tool from table1
    )
```

Now you can follow table creation(table creation by using another table) according to your dbms.